# Scraping a table (CSS build) from online store with Python Scrapy Pandas

Tags: python, css, pandas, scrapy, screen-scraping

I try to get a clean table from a online store - the section with "Technische Daten" - https://www.coolblue.de/produkt/863600/aeg-l6fb64470.html#product-specifications

The CSS selector I use is `section.js-specifications-section`

> response.css('section.js-specifications-section').extract()

Is it possible to extract these datas as a simple HTML (unformated) table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need loop through each spec item within the table. Here's how you can achieve it

```
data = {}
for spec in response.css('section.js-specifications-section dl'):
    key = ''.join(spec.css('dt ::text').extract()).strip()
    val = ''.join(spec.css('dd ::text').extract()).strip()
    data[key] = val
print(data)
```

This will give you a dictionary of all the specs. You can format it however you want.

Comment: @sagun-shresta
Thanks for your valued answer. So I have to loop through the CSS "table construct". I stuck to the fact that it is a table structure that can possibly be addressed as HTML. But they are pure CSS components.

Thank you for providing me with code on the best way to extract it (one at a time, piece by piece). Very nice from you!

I'll tackle it tomorrow ...

Do we not have a function or routine for such a data accumulation that "sees" it as our eye sees it: as a table. And accordingly cuts out the data and reassembles it on my server? No, right?

Comment: @Legion No such function is not possible. With CSS you can make any tags look like table and css selector doesn't work that way. You will probably have to figure out a logic for each structure separately.

Comment: @Sagun-Shresta Understand. Then I will focus on outputting the parsed data (generally meant in these constellations) with the same CSS formatting - as required. So save the style files at the same time. OK.

Comment: @Legion can you mark this answer as correct if it solved your problem? That will help other people looking for similar problems.

Comment: @Sagun-Shresta I did it a few days ago. It's just not accepted because I need 2 more reputation votes. Look, I click again and get: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by people with fewer than 15 reputations will be recorded but will not change the publicly displayed score. -> If someone gives my post a grade here, I need another to get the 15 reputations. I am sorry that I cannot (officially) rate it (yet). But it will appear automatically because I have already marked it.

Comment: @Sagun_Shresta ....Ah the "Accept Answer" button - got it. Realized that just right now. Well clicked now, of course.